# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined yii2, JSON, AJAX, Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to highlight all the dates that have been scheduled. Ajax and JSON working correctly, I get all the results on console.log(), except for this error when I try to go through the array. But the array has data in it and shows up on console.log. What am I doing wrong? Please help!!!!

```
'beforeShowDay'=> new JsExpression
    ('  
            function(date) { 
        $.ajax({
                url: "taskslist",
                dataType: "json",
        data: 
            {
                id: '.$CERTIFICATION_PERIOD_ID.',
            },
    success: function(data) 
            { 
                jQuery.parseJSON = function( data ) 
                    {
                        return JSON.parse( data + "" );
                    };

            if (data !== null) 
                {   

                    var TaskScheduleEmployee = [];
                    var TaskScheduleDates = [];

                    $.each(data, function (index, task)
                            {
                            var TASK_SCHEDULE_DATE = task.TASK_SCHEDULE_DATE;

                                var EMPLOYEE_ID = task.EMPLOYEE_ID;
                            }

                        );


                TaskScheduleDates = $.map(data, function(task)
                                            { return task.TASK_SCHEDULE_DATE;
                                            }
                                          );
                TaskScheduleEmployee = $.map(data, function(task)
                                            { return task.EMPLOYEE_ID;
                                            }
                                          );

                        for (var i = 0; i < TaskScheduleDates.length; i++) 
                            {

                                var d = date.getDate();
                                var m =  date.getMonth();
                                m += 1;  // JavaScript months are 0-11
                                var y = date.getFullYear();

                                var dateToCheck = (y + "-" + m + "-" + d);
                                    if (TaskScheduleDates[i] == dateToCheck) 
                                        {
                                            return [true, "ui-state-highlight", TaskScheduleEmployee[i]];
                                        }
                            }
                        return [true, ""];


                }
            else 
                {
                    alert("We are sorry, we couldnot load the Episode");
                }
        }
});




        }
'),
```

Comment: Why aree you redefining `jQuery.parseJSON`? But the problem seems to be that you never call `jQuery.parseJSON`

Comment: If this  return JSON.parse( data + "" ); is what you mean. I got it from yii2 manual because JSON was not returning results and that was the solution.

Comment: The data is being returned correctly and I do not get any error until I add this  part:   `for (var i = 0; i < TaskScheduleDates.length; i++) 
                            {var d = date.getDate();var m =  date.getMonth();m += 1; var y = date.getFullYear();var dateToCheck = (y + "-" + m + "-" + d); if (TaskScheduleDates[i] == dateToCheck) 
                                        {return [true, "ui-state-highlight", TaskScheduleEmployee[i]];
                                        }
                            }
                        return [true, ""];
`